# How to set a value received by hitting the first endpoint to a filter in the second endpoint?

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to show two kinds of data in two lists in a view.

- (1)start_date
- (2)the temperatures of each day from start_date(1) to today

in the case of my code, (1)start_date is shown well, but (2)the temperatures have a problem because each list should show different data but they show the same data in each list...
[image]

Although I can check when each method is called, they make deferent data in the console like below, the simulator shows the same data...

The result in the console:

```
temp_info
25.7
24.9
temp_info
25.6
25.7
24.9
24.1
23.5
25.7
26.4
23.7
23.0
24.4
26.1
```

How could I resolve this problem?

---

Here are the codes:

JsonModel.swift

```
import Foundation

struct DbVegetableInfos: Codable,Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var start_date: String
}

struct WeatherAveInfos:Codable,Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var ave_temp: Float
}
```

AppState.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine
import UIKit

class AppState: ObservableObject {

 @Published var arrayDbVegetableInfos:[DbVegetableInfos]?
 @Published var weatherAveInfos:[WeatherAveInfos]?


func makeGetCallVegetableInfos() {
    // Set up the URL request
    let endpoint: String = "https://sample.com/api/info/"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.addValue("token xxxxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
    // set up the session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    
    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET")
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        // make sure we got data
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do{ self.arrayDbVegetableInfos = try JSONDecoder().decode([DbVegetableInfos].self, from: responseData)
            }catch{
                print("Error: did not decode")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
}


func makeGetCallWeatherAveTemp(start_date:String ) {
    
    // Set up the URL request
    let endpoint: String = "https://sample.com/api/weather_ave/?start_date=\(start_date)"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.addValue("token xxxxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
    // set up the session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET")
            return
        }
        // make sure we got data
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do{ self.weatherAveInfos = try JSONDecoder().decode([WeatherAveInfos].self, from: responseData)
                print("temp_info")
                for info in self.weatherAveInfos!{
                    print(info.ave_temp)
                }
            }catch{
                print("Error: did not decode")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

HomeView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
              VStack{
                    ForEach(appState.arrayDbVegetableInfos ?? []){ info in
                        VStack{
                            VegetableInfoRow(info:info)
                        }.background(Color(.secondarySystemFill))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(.top)
                        .padding(.leading)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                  }
            }.onAppear(){
                appState.makeGetCallVegetableInfos()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VegetableInfoRow.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct VegetableInfoRow: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    var info:DbVegetableInfos
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    VStack{
                        Text("start_date：").padding()
                        Text(stringToStringDate(stringDate: info.start_date, format: "yyyy-MM-dd"))
                    }
                }
                Divider()
                    .padding()
                VStack{
                    VStack{
                        Text("progress_temperature：").padding()
                        ForEach(appState.weatherAveInfos ?? []){ info in
                            Text(String(info.ave_temp))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(){
            appState.makeGetCallWeatherAveTemp(start_date: info.start_date)
        }
    }
}

func stringToStringDate(stringDate: String, format:String) -> String {
    let formatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    let newDate =  formatter.date(from: stringDate)!
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    return formatter.string(from: newDate)
}
```

---

Xcode:Version 12.0.1

Comment: You need to have some kind of connection between the two model objects

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, these data are from `DRF` API, so do I have to connect in models on the `Django` side?

Comment: I have no idea what DRF or Django is but you are downloading weather data for a given start_date but every time you do so you overwrite the content of weatherAveInfos in AppState, instead you need store your data per start_date somehow locally